# How to render a sorted collection from unsorted data in Backbone?

Tags: sorting, backbone.js

I'm fetching unsorted data from a server and want to display it in a sorted list using Backbone. For that purpose I'm using a `comparator` in the collection. However, Backbone fires the `add` events in an inconvenient order when adding multiple models to a collection at once.

**Here's an example illustrating my problem** (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5wtnjj8j/2/):

In the `initialize` function of the `PersonCollectionView` I'm adding three persons to the collection (note that they are not sorted correctly). Each time Backbone inserts one of these models into the collection it fires an `add` event and my `personAdded` function is called. This function outputs the name of the inserted person and the index at which it is inserted.

This is the output I get:

```
insert "Alice" at index: 0
insert "Eve" at index: 2
insert "Bob" at index: 1
```

Obviously, the indices are correct (i.e., sorted by name). *But why does Backbone fire the* `add` *events in the order that the models are specified in, not in the order of the indices?*

I think this behavior is counter-intuitive because it makes it hard to build a sorted list of views. For example, imagine that I want to build a `<ul>` for the models. Inserting Alice would work (because her index is 0), but when the second `add` event arrives, I'm about to insert Eve at index 2 without having received Bob at index 1 first.

**Is there a particular reason why Backbone fires the** `add` **events in the 'wrong' order and is there a way to receive the events sorted by index?**

---

**Model**

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: 'Unknown'
    }
});
```

**Collection**

```
var PersonCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,
    comparator: 'name'
});
```

**View**

```
var PersonCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new PersonCollection();
        this.collection.on('add', this.personAdded, this);

        var models = [{name: 'Alice'}, {name: 'Eve'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
        this.collection.add(models);
    },

    personAdded: function(model, collection, options) {
        var index = collection.indexOf(model);
        var message = 'insert "' + model.get('name') + '" at index: ' + index + '<br>';

        $('body').append(message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem is to sort the models list before adding it to the collection.

```
var models = [{name: 'Alice'}, {name: 'Eve'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
this.collection.add(_.sortBy(models, 'name'));
```

Here's an example [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/9jateL1o/)

Backbone is adding the models in the order you gave them to it and sort them after that, and before the first event reach your `personAdded` function Backbone has already added all the models that's why you got index 2 for `Eve` and not 1

---

For the `fetch` call, try to redefine the `parse` function:

```
var PersonCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  ...
  parse: function(response) {
    return _.sortBy(response, 'name')
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for my example. However, when I use fetch to get the models from the server I have no chance to sort them with Underscore before they are being inserted into the collection.

Comment: When you fetch the models from the server there's no add event (but `sync` event) and the collection sort itself after adding all the models, so where's your problem with that?

Comment: I just checked again: calling fetch on the collection triggered an `add` event for each model received and a `sync` event after all models have been added. The problem is exactly the same as before: the indices of the models are sorted, but the `add` events are triggered in the wrong order (i.e., the order in which the models were sent by the server).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can also create a new collection and instantiate the collection with the unsorted array

```
initialize: function() {

        var models = [{name: 'Alice'}, {name: 'Eve'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
        this.collection = new PersonCollection(models );

        this.collection.on('add', this.personAdded, this);
    },
```

another approach you can take is declare your collection add binding after your items have been added.

```
   initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new PersonCollection();

        var models = [{name: 'Alice'}, {name: 'Eve'}, {name: 'Bob'}];
        this.collection.add(models);

        this.collection.on('add', this.personAdded, this);
    },
```

Edit: alternative approach to creating a collection view. It is generally not a good idea for the view to know where/what the container is (body in this case). It's a better practice to return the content of view from the render() function. Then add the view's el to the body.

```
var PersonCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(opts) {        
        var models = [{name: 'Alice', index:1}, {name: 'Eve', index:2}, {name: 'Bob', index:3}];

        this.collection = new PersonCollection(models);
        this.collection.on('add', this.personAdded, this);
    },
    personAdded: function(model, collection, options) {
        var index = collection.indexOf(model);
        var message = 'insert "' + model.get('name') + '" at index: ' + model.get('index') + '<br>';

        this.$el.append(message);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(model){
            this.$el.append('insert "' + model.get('name') + '" at index: ' + model.get('index')+"</br>");
        },this);
        return this;    //making it chainable (render().$el);
    }
});

//from server
var personCollectionView = new PersonCollectionView();

$('body').append(personCollectionView.render().el);
```

Comment: In both cases, the views are not rendered because of the missing `add` events. But I guess that could be done manually...

Comment: Thanks for your edit. In my example I just add the output directly to the body to keep it simple. In the real application I'm creating a view for each person.